# Redux not updating a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component that is passed a "user" prop from Redux that looks something like this:

```
user: {
    user: {
        photos: []
    },
    userIsFetching: false,
    userIsFetchError: false
}
```

When "photos" is updated, React will not rerender. I can see in the Redux log that "photos" does get updated. Is this problem due to "photos" being deeply nested?

Here's the reducer:

```
function deleteUserPhoto(user, id) {
    return {
        ...user,
        photos: deletePhoto(user.photos, id)
    };
}

function deletePhoto(photos, id) {
    return photos.filter(photo =>
        photo.id !== id
    );
}

export function user(state, action) {

    if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
        state = {
            user: null,
            userIsFetching: false,
            userIsFetchError: false
        }
    }

    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                userIsFetching: true
            };
        case USER_RESPONSE:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.user
            };
        case USER_RESPONSE_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                userIsFetching: false,
                userIsFetchError: true
            };
        case PHOTO_DELETE:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: deleteUserPhoto(state.user, action.id)
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're most likely overwriting the `user` property with something else.

Comment: Agreed. While I can't immediately identify the problem, it can be tricky to get nested objects right, and there can be subtle ways to mutate something you shouldn't mutate. You might consider something like https://github.com/gaearon/normalizr to flatten your store. Also, are you undoing your flags when the response comes back?

Comment: The flags are for the original user fetch. When I interact with the page (e.g. trigger an onClick), the page updates with the correct photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My stupid mistake. The props were updating but I was checking the state (which was initialized by the props) and I didn't update the state on prop change. I was only using state because it's required by the dropzone mixin I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the case in your real code, but from what I can see in your code samples: in `deletePhoto` method, calling `filter` should throw a TypeError as `photos` is undefined in your initial state.

There is no problem at all with deeply nested properties as long as a new state is returned. It can becomes cumbersome at some point but libraries like ImmutableJS help us to manage very complex kind of state.
A view not being updated after calling an action is a common problem usually caused by mutated state: http://rackt.org/redux/docs/Troubleshooting.html